# How to use regular expression in shell to match filenames?

Tags: linux, shell

Now I have two folders:

Folder_1 contains 3 files: a_v1.txt, b_v1.txt, c_v1.txt.

Folder_2 also contains 3 files: a_v2.txt, b_v2.txt, c_v2.txt.

I'm trying to use regular expression to match files which have same strings in front of v1 and v2 (e.g {a_v1.txt, a_v2.txt}). I have succeeded in realizing this in Python by using `"^(.+?)v1", "^(.+?)v2"`, but I just start to learning Shell and still not familiar with that. Could someone please help me about this?

Comment: Given the two Folders, please show the desired output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would probably not use regular expressions at all in this situation but instead match the filenames from one directory, and then construct names of the files that you'd like to pick up from the other directory:

```
for name1 in Folder_1/*_v1.txt; do
    name2="Folder_2/$(basename "$name1" _v1.txt)_v2.txt"

    if [ -f "$name2" ]; then
        printf 'Have "%s" and "%s"\n' "$name1" "$name2"
    else
        printf 'Missing "%s"\n' "$name2"
    fi
done
```

This loops over the pathnames of the files matching `*_v1.txt` in the first directory, and for each pathname it constructs the pathname corresponding to the file that we expect to find in the other directory.  This is done by use of the `basename` utility which returns the filename portion of a pathname with an optional suffix removed.

We prepend and append the appropriate strings to the output of this utility and then tests to see whether the new pathname corresponds to a regular file (or a symbolic link to one).

Would you want to do something to the pairs of found files, you would do so in the first branch of the `if` statement, or after the `if` statement in this equivalent reformulation of the loop:

```
for name1 in Folder_1/*_v1.txt; do
    name2="Folder_2/$(basename "$name1" _v1.txt)_v2.txt"

    if [ ! -f "$name2" ]; then
        printf 'Missing "%s"\n' "$name2"
        continue
    fi

    printf 'Have "%s" and "%s"\n' "$name1" "$name2"
done
```

Testing:

```
$ tree
.
|-- Folder_1
|   |-- a_v1.txt
|   |-- b_v1.txt
|   |-- c_v1.txt
|   `-- d_v1.txt
`-- Folder_2
    |-- a_v2.txt
    |-- b_v2.txt
    `-- c_v2.txt

2 directories, 7 files
```

Output of the loop:

```
Have "Folder_1/a_v1.txt" and "Folder_2/a_v2.txt"
Have "Folder_1/b_v1.txt" and "Folder_2/b_v2.txt"
Have "Folder_1/c_v1.txt" and "Folder_2/c_v2.txt"
Missing "Folder_2/d_v2.txt"
```